# what is the use of serverside encryption in java while travelling data through network

Tags: java, security, encryption

> What is the use of server side password encryption in java.If we are
>   doing server side     encryption then the password already sent
>   through network. Because of this i can provide     the security to
>   password from administrators or who can see in the database.
>
> But my question here is how i can prevent the attacks which come while
>   travelling data    in the network.

I need some explanation about this.Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Using [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

Comment: The question in its present state cannot be answered at all. You talk about a network / database / passwords and there is no mention of what `use case` you'd like to address, what `protocol` you're talking about; what kind of `attack` you're trying to prevent. The reference to passwords and databases could well be red herring.

Comment: i mean attack is capturing the data .Nothing more than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a socket-level encryption scheme like SSL to protect the traffic as it crosses the network.

Comment: then what is the use of encryption in java using secureRandom,KeyGenerator...etc in server side

Comment: That will allow you to do things like encrypt the data before you store it to the database.  Sometimes more people have access to the database then should.  It can also be used to implement your own SSL-like protocol.  It can be useful if you don't trust the person that makes requests against your server but you don't want to or can't implement authentication.  You can use it to sign a message that you only want a certain person to be able to read similar to PGP.  There are many uses.

Comment: what about client side encryption.Is it good to do

Comment: When working with encryption you need to 1) Determine what you want to protect.  2) Determine who you want to protect it from and then 3) Figure out where attackers could get at your data and protect it.  Which encryption scheme to use and where to use it will differ for every application.

Comment: are there any frameworks available for encryption

Comment: Yes, there is the JCE.  One example implementation is http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28662/discussion-between-psr-and-pace)

Comment: let us continue discussion in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28662/discussion-between-psr-and-pace

Comment: will you come to chat